# Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit doesn't work, if it is used in a Soft-phone loaded form a non standard port (80/443)

Tags: service-cloud-console, opencti

The toolkit works seamlessly if used in a Soft-phone loaded form a standard port like the following URL:

[image]

But if I reference a non-standard port (e.g. 8443), the API just doesn't accept any request. The toolkit is silently discarding the postMessages without throwing an error nor calling the callback function.
Unfortunately we cannot change the port 8443 to 443 in our production environment.

[image]

The following is the simple code example for reproducing the issue (the code is copied almost 1:1 form the salesforce developer guide [Console Integration Toolkit Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_setcustomconsolecomponentbuttonstyle.htm)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script 
              src="https://c.na1.visual.force.com/support/console/32.0/integration.js"
              type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setBackground() {
                  window.sforce.console
                             .setCustomConsoleComponentButtonStyle(
                                          "background-color: #008000;"
                  );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Issue Demo</h1>
            <a 
                 href="#" 
                 onClick="setBackground();return false">
                      Click here to set Background
            </a> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Has anyone came across the same issue before? 
Is there an open issue for this behavior?
Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a setting to whiltelist other domains for the console toolkit. Enlisting **localhost:8443** did the trick. This is mandatory for the [Console Integration Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/) but not for the [Open CTI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_cti/) api.

**Whitelisting domains in Salesforce Console:**

- From **Setup**, click **Create | Apps**.
- Select a Salesforce console app.
- Click **Edit**.
- Go to the section **Whitelist Domains**.
- Add the server and the port to the whitelist
- Click Save.